# Creating a directory on Ubuntu using ansible playbook

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, directory

I'm trying to create an ec2 instance through ansible playbook and then run a few commands on it. The ec2 instance is created sucessfully and also ssh'd into it. Now, when I try to run this command:

```
- name: Create scripts directory
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: /scripts
    state: directory
    mode: '0755'
```

An error is generated:

```
{"changed": false, "msg": "There was an issue creating /scripts as requested: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/scripts'", "path": "/scripts"}
```

I have specified the mode as 0755 which is read write execute permissions. So why is it giving an error, the same error even for 0777? I'm new to ansible and Ubuntu in general.

Comment: your user have not the access to write to that directory. So, You can only read (Read Access) from that directory.

Comment: How to add access to write for that user?

Comment: you have to use the option become to give the root right for your users..your user have to be in group sudoer.. see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to add the option become to use the admin privilege (your user have to be sudo er...)

```
- name: Create scripts directory
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: /scripts
    state: directory
    mode: '0755'
  become: yes
```

here you create a folder on level root, are you sure to do that?

To specify a password for sudo, run ansible-playbook with --ask-become-pass (-K for short). If you run a playbook utilizing become and the playbook seems to hang, most likely it is stuck at the privilege escalation prompt. Stop it with CTRL-c, then execute the playbook with -K and the appropriate password.

Answer (score 0):

Your Ansible user doesn't have the required privileges to create a directory at that level. Either use another user (bad option) or make sure the user has sudo capabilities and use become: yes to execute the command as sudo